# How to create new goose database migration (golang)

Tags: go, go-gin, goose

I use goget to install goose for database migration following https://github.com/pressly/goose. But when i use `goose create SomeThing` it not working,and i dont now why. 
Please help me!

I have created successfully. I go get following url https://bitbucket.org/liamstask/goose/ . and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed in recent versions of https://github.com/pressly/goose.